# How to get email if test case run in AWS lambda function fails

Tags: aws-lambda, python-unittest, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following test cases executed in AWS Lambda. I want to get email alarm if any test case not passes.

To do that, I create a cloud watch alarm, which triggers SNS to send email to me if this Lambda Error metrics has error >=1 (I refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-create-alarm.html)). However I never get email as expected, because even test case fails, the lambda function itself executes correctly. Only if I write some typo in lambda function, I will get an email alarm. Of course I do not want to write code that way.

So, how can I get email if any test case not passes?

```
import unittest

def test_case_pass(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)

def test_case_notpass(self):
    self.assertTrue(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish to SNS from the Lambda if a test fails.

```
import boto3
sns = boto3.client('sns')
# Do tests
# If test fails
    sns.publish(TopicArn='topicarn', Message='something went wrong' )
```

Related Boto 3 Docs here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish